# Permanently mount multiple directories from different disks under /

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

I have SSD and HDD. Some directories like `/var`, `/srv` and `/tmp` should be on HDD, while `/boot`, `/usr` and `/lib` on SSD. But do I have to create separate partition for every single directory? I want to have 2 or so partitions. One for each disk and distribute directories as needed. Is it possible and how?

I've heard about symlinks, `mount --bind`, **mhddfs** but:

- symlinks are treated differently by tools like **cp**, so I'm not sure if it's safe to have main system directories symlinked
- I have no idea how can I use `mount --bind` or **mhddfs** in `fstab`

Comment: What about using the SSD as a cache? `/lib` can't be on a separate partition and the same is [*recommended*](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/) for `/usr`.

Answer (score 2):

I never used this but I guess you can mount / directory at ssd device.
Then create a folder named /hdd
After, create your desired folders like /hdd/var /hdd/srv /hdd/tmp.

And use the bind mount to update those entries

```
mount --bind /hdd/var /var
mount --bind /hdd/tmp /tmp
```

For the just create the /boot, /usr, /lib  folders. No need for remount.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have lots of partitions and you also want the flexibility of moving things around, I recommend using **LVM**.

Create the `/boot` partition on the SSD and another 2 large partitions: one on the HDD, the another one on the SSD. These 2 partitions will be physical volumes (PVs) for the LVM. Add them to a volume group (VG), then create a logical volume (LV) for each directory on the desired PV. If you discover later that `/var` should be on the SSD, not on the HDD, you can use [**pvmove**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvmove.8.html) to move its corresponding LV from the HDD to the SSD.

Example:

```
pvcreate /dev/disk/by-id/hdd-part1
pvcreate /dev/disk/by-id/sdd-part2 # part1 is /boot
vgcreate my_vg /dev/disk/by-id/hdd-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/sdd-part2
lvcreate -n root -L 6G my_vg /dev/disk/by-id/sdd-part2
lvcreate -n var -L 2G my_vg /dev/disk/by-id/hdd-part1
lvcreate -n srv -L 10G my_vg /dev/disk/by-id/hdd-part1
pvmove -n var /dev/disk/by-id/hdd-part2 /dev/disk/by-id/sdd-part2
```

I want to emphasize that **pvmove** can also move only fragments of a PV called physical extents (PEs). The default size of a PE is 4 MiB and it can be set when the VG is created.

Answer (score 1):

Bind mounts should accomplish what you are trying to do. You can use bind mounts with ease in fstab: a bind mount fstab entry looks like

```
/path/to/original /mount/point none bind 0 0
```

Just note that you need something mounted to / to begin with, so I would recommend mounting your SSD to /, and then bind mounting various directories from your HDD as you see fit.
So an fstab like (assuming ext4 partitions, change as necessary)

```
### /etc/fstab ###

# Mount SSD to /
/dev/disk/by-uuid/your-ssd-partition-uuid / ext4 0 1

# Mount HDD somewhere (in this case /mnt/hdd)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/your-hdd-partition-uuid /mnt/hdd ext4 0 2

# Bind mounts
/mnt/hdd/var /var none bind 0 0
/mnt/hdd/srv /srv none bind 0 0
/mnt/hdd/tmp /tmp none bind 0 0
```

You can also have a dedicated "root" directory for /, say on your ssd, this would make fstab look like

```
### /etc/fstab ###

# Mount SSD somewhere
/dev/disk/by-uuid/your-ssd-partition-uuid /mnt/ssd ext4 0 1

# Mount HDD somewhere (in this case /mnt/hdd)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/your-hdd-partition-uuid /mnt/hdd ext4 0 2

# Mount /
/mnt/ssd/root / none bind 0 0

# Other Bind mounts
/mnt/hdd/var /var none bind 0 0
/mnt/hdd/srv /srv none bind 0 0
/mnt/hdd/tmp /tmp none bind 0 0
/mnt/ssd/lib /lib none bind 0 0
/mnt/ssd/usr /usr none bind 0 0
```

Comment: Have you tested the second configuration?